# Cardinality of Cantor-like set for which deleted intervals have length $\frac{\alpha}{3}$ instead of $\frac{1}{3}$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, cantor-set

I have been reading the book Modern Real Analysis by Ziemer and have come to an exercise in the chapter on measure theory that I am having trouble with. The exercise concerns a Cantor-like set where instead of the middle $\frac{1}{3}$ being deleted on each iteration the middle $\frac{\alpha}{3}$ is deleted with $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Let $C$ be the Cantor set and $C_{\alpha}$ be the Cantor-like set.

The exercise asks the reader to prove that $C_{\alpha}$ is nowhere dense, has cardinality $c = 2^{\aleph_{0}}$, and Lebesgue measure $1 - \alpha$. I am able to show that $C_{\alpha}$ is nowhere dense and that its Lebesgure measure is $1 - \alpha$, but I am having trouble finding a way to prove that $C_{\alpha} = c$. Can someone help with this ?

Comment: How would the proof be any different than that for the usual Cantor set?

Comment: It's still true for any $x \in C_\alpha$ that you can generate a sequence $\{0, 1\}^\omega$ by selecting at each deletion, whether you're to the left or right of the deleted middle. Presumably, you know that such a set has cardinality $\aleph_1$.

Comment: The cardinality of that Cantor set (or of any "generalized Cantor set" in the reals) is $c,$ which is not necessarily equal to $\aleph_{1}.$ @fleablood: Probably the proof would have to be significantly changed if the proof under consideration for the usual Cantor set was strongly based on ternary expansions and $\alpha$ is irrational.

Comment: In the book they use the fact that the set of real numbers in [0,1] with ternary expansions that have no '1' digit is the Cantor set and that this set has a one-to-one correspondence with $\{0,2\}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: @scipio, $\aleph_1$ and $\mathfrak c$ are two different notions.

Comment: Yes, I changed the text of the post to reflect. I didn't realize that.  Is the fact that $c = \aleph_{1}$ is not necessarily true due to the continuum hypothesis not necessarily being true ?

Comment: "In the book they use the fact that the set of real numbers in [0,1] with ternary expansions that have no '1' digit is the Cantor set and that this set has a one-to-one correspondence with {0,2}N" Ah.. well you *could* do something similar. Make a decimal tertiary system where the number $0.a_1a_2a_3a_4.... = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\begin{cases}0&a_k=0\\(1-\frac \alpha 3)^k&a_k-1\\(1-\frac \alpha 3)^k+\frac {\alpha^k}{3^k}&a_k =2\end{cases}$ and it's still the same proof... might not be worth the effort (have to proof this every real number has a distinct representation in this system).